# サブドメインにドットは使えますか？

Tags: network

みなさんこのサイトには[スタックオーバーフロー・メタ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)というサイト全体の機能改善やサイトに対する意見や討議などを行う場所があるのをご存知でしょうか？
左上の [StackExchange] >> [スタックオーバーフローMeta] という順番でアクセスできます。

ところで、いま気づいたんですがこのスタックオーバーフロー・メタのドメインは
`meta.ja.stackoverflow.com`
となっています。

スタックオーバーフローのドメインの
`ja.stackoverflow.com`
における `ja` がサブドメインとなっていることは理解できるのですが

`meta.ja.stackoverflow.com`
のように `meta.ja` というのもサブドメインと呼ばれるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 5):

文脈によって用法にぶれがあるので、サブドメインと言う用語に本来の意味とか厳密な正解はありません。

例えば「ドメイン」=「希望して取得できる単位」(example.com、example.co.jp、などのレベル)というニュアンスが強い文脈だと、そのドメインに対してそれ以下の階層すべてひっくるめて「サブドメイン」というとらえ方も出来ます。出来ることは出来るのですが、だからといって`meta.ja`が`stackoverflow.com`のサブドメイン、という言い方はあまりしないかな、と思います。

`meta`が`ja.stackoverflow.com`のサブドメイン(`ja.stackoverflow.com`の`meta`サブドメイン)とは一般的に言いますので、「ある階層から見たときの直下の1階層」という感覚が強いのかもしれません。

(ホスト名+ドメイン、というとらえ方をする文脈だと`meta.ja.stackoverflow.com`の`meta`はホスト名であってドメイン名じゃない、ともなってしまいます。)

ドメインは階層構造になっていますよ、ドメイン名は`meta`とか`ja`とかの「名前」を`.`で区切って下位から上位に並べたものですよ、という概念のほうをしっかり押さえておいて、用語そのものには余りこだわらない方が良いかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

ドメイン階層という意味では、`ja.stackoverflow.com`が`stackoverflow.com`のサブドメインなのであって、`ja`だけを取り出してサブドメインというのではありません。同じように`meta.ja.stackoverflow.com`は`ja.stackoverflow.com`のサブドメインです。

[追記]回答を書いた後でネット上の記事を見直してみたら、『`ja`の部分が「サブドメイン」です』と書いてある記事がかなり見つかりますね。こういった本来の意味とはちょっとずれた使い方の場合でも「サブドメインのそのまたサブドメイン」という考え方は通じると思うので、回答本体はそのままにしておきます。